# Why i am not able to run Spring program?

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

While i am trying to run spring program in eclipse i get following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    BeanFactory cannot be resolved to a type
    XmlBeanFactory cannot be resolved to a type
    FileSystemResource cannot be resolved to a type
    triangle cannot be resolved

    at Org.koushik.javabrains.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:8)
```

I tried to resolve this error. I also download spring.jar file and put it in the classpath.But, still i am getting error.I also want whole spring.jar which should include 
all spring.jar file.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: When using newer versions of Spring (> 2.5) there is no more spring.jar. I also strongly suggest using something like Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies instead of trying to figure out what jars you need.

Comment: @M.Deinum could u provide link for Maven or Gradle?and Why for Spring >2.5 Maven or Gradle should be used.

Comment: It's not that Gradle or Maven should be used for spring>2.5 it will reduce your effort . You just specify the Spring modules u need and Maven will download all the jar files for you(Dependency management). If u do that manually u need to download Spring Jars and also some other jars that spring jars might depend on which becomes very tiresome most of the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage your dependencies use tools like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org), [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org) or [Ant + Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). Those will make your life a whole lot easier, the dependencies will be managed and you will get also all transitive dependencies (the dependencies the framework you use depends on). This will save you a lot of searching around the internet.

With either of these tools you create a build file (ant and maven use XML, Gralde uses Groovy for that) and express your dependencies.

For example this build file for gradle, `build.gradle` will create a jar and use all the dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'        
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '3.2.5.RELEASE'        
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

This `gradle.build` will add the needed spring jars and the dependencies it needs for that.

Comment: I try to add dependencies from Eclipse Market Place. But, I am  not able to find which Maven need to install. How could i find which Maven is suitable?

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving that exception because you dont have the right jar files.

You need these jars for a Spring IOC/DI module based project.
You can download the jars from [**here**](http://repo.springsource.org/release/org/springframework/spring/3.2.4.RELEASE/)

*Learn and start using a dependency management tool like Deinum said*

[image]