# ClassPathResource cannot be resolved to a type in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am new in spring , i am learning spring and this is my first spring program.
i am made this program in eclipse ide when i trying getdata from IOC then give error
1.ClassPathResource cannot be resolved to a type.
2.BeanFactory cannot be resolved to a type.
3.XmlBeanFactory cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Please post the necessary parts of your program where you try to load resources and error stacktrace

Comment: its most likely because either your jar files are not configured properly or pom.xml needs to be updated with the right artifacts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174976/why-i-am-not-able-to-run-spring-program You need maven to manage dependencies.